# mod_rewrite to default to index.php if first backreference ($1) is not a file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I try to read a url scheme for a web application using `mod_rewrite`.

I'm using one or multiple "variables" using a directory structure in the URL:

`www.myWebApp.com/create/12345` should be rewritten to `myWebApp.com/create.php?id=12345`
`www.myWebApp.com/share/12345` should be rewritten to `myWebApp.com/share.php?id=12345`

I have this working using

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*) $1.php?id=$2 [NC,L]
```

However, if the url is `simply www.myWebApp.com/12345`, the rewrite rule has to know that the first backreference (`12345`) is not a valid file (`12345.php` does not exist), so it should interpret the URL as `index.php?id=12345`.

The basic condition is to check if the first argument exists as a php file. If it does, serve this page. And if there is a second argument, use this as the "id"

These are some examples and their desired results:

`1. www.myWebApp.com/create` ("create.php" exists)
=> www.myWebApp.com/create.php

`2. www.myWebApp.com/create/MUymnF50x`
=> www.myWebApp.com/create.php?id=MUymnF50x`

`3. www.myWebApp.com/create/MUymnF50x/F5jLKW0nJAc=`
=> www.myWebApp.com/create.php?id=MUymnF50x&token=F5jLKW0nJAc=

If the first argument does not exist as a php file, simply serve "index.php" and append the argument as its "id".

`4. www.myWebApp.com/MUymnF50x ("MUymnF50x.php" does not exist)`
    => www.myWebApp.com/index.php?id=MUymnF50x

`5. www.myWebApp.com/MUymnF50x/F5jLKW0nJAc=`
    => www.myWebApp.com/index.php?id=MUymnF50x&token=F5jLKW0nJAc=

Answer (score 1):

You can use these 2 rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.php [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?id=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?id=$2&token=$3 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1&token=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks. I've got this working for the scenario in my original post. However, it fails in other cases which I have to deal with. please have a look at the details I added to my original post.

Comment: Not a good habit to change nature of the question like this. Since you are new here I am posting an update to my answer.